# Why streisand vpn script doesn't change my country?(but change ip)

Tags: security, vpn, digital-ocean, l2tp

I successfully install [streisand](https://github.com/jlund/streisand) with openvpn/l2TP/IPsec on debian 7 on digital ocean.
My ip address changed successfully, but why country doesn't changed?(For example, using such services like http://whatismycountry.com/ doesn't show vpn server country)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved , i also tried other vpn hosts and the problem appeared. I used 2ip.ru project for checking country and whatismycountry.com but when i use another service http://www.geoiptool.com/ , it show correct country.